# Are some achievements impossible to get?

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

In Starcraft II there are some achievements that require you to use abilities that were patched out with balance updates. I am talking specifically about the achievements in the "Versus" group. But it might be the case that other achievements could be unreachable. For example there is an achievement where you need to kill a couple of units with the Raven Seeker Missle. Well, good luck with that because the seeker missle was nerfed to do 0 dmg in the last big balance patch. Is it somehow possible to get that achievement?

Comment: IIRC, Blizzard has a special category of achievements called "Feats of Strength" (or something) where they put achievements that can no longer be earned.  People who got the achievement when it was possible will be able to see their accomplishments there, and everyone else will know it's impossible now.  Are these achievements you're looking at categorized as Feats of Strength?

Comment: No they are categorized in Versus. One example is kill 6 Units with the seeker missle. The second example is get 20 units into the vortex of the mothership (it doesn't have that ability any longer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've purchased Wings of the Liberty and/or Heart of the Swarm, I think you can still [play these expansions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/if-i-get-hots-can-i-still-play-wol-with-friends). This way you get those abilities back and will be able to complete the achievements.

However, I'm not sure if that will allow you to complete every achievement in SC2.

#### Update

This option was removed from the game, however you still can play expansions in [custom games (Custom → Melee)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4eVp.jpg). Not sure if the achievements are granted in this mode.

Comment: There is no option to set the expansion level in the gameplay options.

Comment: I'm sorry. Can't check it myself right now.

Comment: They moved it to the Custom tab. You can't play ladder with the old expansions anymore.